# Rich faces : how to add static text beside value on InputNumberSlider tooltip?

Tags: java, javascript, jsf-2, richfaces

I'm Using rich faces 4 
I'm using input number slider

```
 <rich:inputNumberSlider value="10" width="500" minValue="1" maxValue="30" step="1"   showInput="false"  enableManualInput="false" showArrows="false" tooltipClass=""  showTooltip="true" label="Days" />
```

i want to add word "Days" in the tool tip , to be "10 Days" instead of "10" .

Comment: [There is no direct support for it](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/inputNumberSlider.jsf?tab=info&cid=558798), May be you could use some javascript hack, Watch [this ticket](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RF-12319)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[RichFaces API on `<rich:inputNumberSlider>`](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/rich_inputNumberSlider.html) says:

> **The "label" attribute is a generic attribute.** The "label" attribute
>   provides an association between the component and the message that the
>   component (indirectly) produced. This attribute defines the parameters
>   of a localized error and informational messages that occur as a result
>   of conversion, validation, or other application actions during the
>   request processing lifecycle. With the help of this attribute you can
>   replace the last parameter substitution token shown in the messages.
>   For example, {1} for "DoubleRangeValidator.MAXIMUM" , {2} for
>   "ShortConverter.SHORT".

In short - label is used in all components as a parameter for jsf messages.

I have looked into [richfaces sources](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.jboss.org/maven2/org.richfaces.ui/richfaces-ui/3.3.2.GA/org/richfaces/renderkit/html/script/SliderScript.js) for `<rich:inputNumberSlider>` ui javascript. It is possible to change javascript in certain places, adding hardcoded 'Days' string. To achieve this I can't think of any other options than recompiling the sources.

I suggest specifying somewhere else, that this slider measures days.